# D3js diagram, after the end of the simulation, the text display position on the connection line is not right

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, d3.js

D3js force guide graph force initialization, the line above the word display position is wrong. When you drag the node, the text returns to the desired position.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhKn0.png)

```
    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
      .links(links)
      .size([width, height])
      .linkDistance(120)
      .charge(-1200)
      .on("tick", tick)
      .start();




    edges_text.attr("class", "textPaths").append('textPath')
      .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) { return '#edgepath' + i })
      .style("pointer-events", "none")
      .text(function (d) { d.relationshipName; });

function tick() {
   
      edges_text.attr('transform', function (d, i) {
        if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
          let bbox = this.getBBox();
          let rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
          let ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
          return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
        }else {
          return 'rotate(0)';
        }
      }).attr('dx', function (d, i) {
          if(d.source.x < d.target.x){
            let source = getCoord(d.target, d.source).split(" ")
            let target = getCoord(d.source, d.target).split(" ")
            return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(target[0] - source[0], 2) + Math.pow(target[1] - source[1], 2)) / 2 - 20;
        }else{
            let source = getCoord(d.source, d.target).split(" ")
            let target = getCoord(d.target, d.source).split(" ")
            return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(target[0] - source[0], 2) + Math.pow(target[1] - source[1], 2)) / 2 - 20;
        }   
        })
        ;
    }
```